# How to install Cryptcat

Tags: windows, installation, cmd.exe

How do you get Cryptcat running on Windows?  The sourceforge - http://sourceforge.net/projects/cryptcat/files/ - link only has .dsp files and other assortments of objects of which what I am supposed to do I am not sure.  There is no .exe, but I imagine you have to install and run from cmd anyways?

I've searched for a bit but surprisingly this apparently isn't a very popular subject.  Frankly, doing this via Linux is easier :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

You need to build it yourself.

---

#### Long Answer

The Windows version is distributed as a zip file `cryptcat-nt-1.2.1.zip` containing source code.

`cryptcat.dsp` is a "Microsoft Developer Studio Generated Build File, Format Version 6.00" so you will need to have Visual Studio installed in order to build the project.

It is possible that Visual Studio is not able to work with the very old build file and you may have to create a new project to get it all working.

Note that this project was last active in 2005, so getting it working may not be an easy task.